# Changing Notification RemoteViews Background Color

Tags: android, service, notifications, themes, android-remoteview

I've a problem changing my Background-Color with the Application-Theme.

```
NotificationCompat.Builder nBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);

TypedValue typedValue = new TypedValue();

getTheme().resolveAttribute(R.attr.colorPrimary, typedValue, true);

int iPrimaryColor = typedValue.data;

getTheme().resolveAttribute(R.attr.colorPrimaryDark, typedValue, true);

int iPrimaryDarkColor = typedValue.data;

Intent notIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
notIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

PendingIntent notOpenOnClick = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, notIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

RemoteViews smallContentView = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.notification_small);
RemoteViews bigContentView = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.notification_expanded);

nBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.not_icon)
    .setOngoing(true)
    .setContentTitle(getCurrentSong().getTitle())
    .setContentIntent(notOpenOnClick);

Notification not = nBuilder.build();

smallContentView.setInt(R.id.not_linLayout, "setBackgroundColor", iPrimaryColor);
smallContentView.setInt(R.id.not_imvDivider, "setBackgroundColor", iPrimaryDarkColor);

bigContentView.setInt(R.id.not_linLayout, "setBackgroundColor", iPrimaryColor);
bigContentView.setInt(R.id.not_imvDivider, "setBackgroundColor", iPrimaryDarkColor);

setListeners(smallContentView);
setListeners(bigContentView);

not.contentView = smallContentView;
not.bigContentView = bigContentView;

if (isPlaying()) {
    not.contentView.setImageViewResource(R.id.not_btnPlayPause, R.drawable.ic_pause_48dp);
    not.bigContentView.setImageViewResource(R.id.not_btnPlayPause, R.drawable.ic_pause_48dp);
}
else {
    not.contentView.setImageViewResource(R.id.not_btnPlayPause, R.drawable.ic_play_48dp);
    not.bigContentView.setImageViewResource(R.id.not_btnPlayPause, R.drawable.ic_play_48dp);
}
```

I already tried this, but the Background of my Notification is still white.
The ID's are correct, the View linLayout is a LinearLayout.

Please keep in mind: The whole codes is invoked in a Service!

Thanks!

Comment: It looks like you're trying to build a media control notification. Please don't use a custom notification for that, but instead use [NotificationCompat.MediaStyle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/NotificationCompat.MediaStyle.html)

Comment: Ok but why is it better to use MediaStyle?

Comment: 1) Works on API 7+ devices 2) Uses the built in styling on Lollipop+ 3) Automatically adapts to the new Android N notification styling 4) Has built in support for a custom background color 5) Has built in support for working around issues with dismissing notifications from foreground services on pre-Lollipop devices 6) Supports adding your MediaSession token to get Android Wear controls working. To name a few.

Comment: You should watch the [Best practices in media playback I/O 2016 talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iIKxyDRjecU)

Comment: Okey great, thanks :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Much of this can be easier done by taking advantage of [NotificationCompat.MediaStyle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/NotificationCompat.MediaStyle.html). It pulls the background color from the [setColor()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html#setColor(int)) call on pre-API 24 devices (and uses that color as an accent on API 24+ devices). This also means you don't need to write any custom RemoteViews code anymore as it relies solely on the actions you add to your notification for media controls:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder nBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
nBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.not_icon)
  .setContentTitle(getCurrentSong().getTitle())
  .setContentIntent(notOpenOnClick);
// This is what sets the background color on <N devices
// It is an accent color on N+ devices
nBuilder.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
// Add actions via nBuilder.addAction()
// Set the style, setShowActionsInCompactView(0) means the first
// action you've added will be shown the non-expanded view
nBuilder.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.MediaStyle()
  .setShowActionsInCompactView(0));
```

You should definitely read over all of the methods available for [MediaStyle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/NotificationCompat.MediaStyle.html) and reivew the [Best Practices in media playback I/O 2016 talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iIKxyDRjecU) for example code and best practices around using notifications. Specifically at [30 minutes into the talk](https://youtu.be/iIKxyDRjecU?t=1800)

Comment: can you post an example code? i tried to find something helpful but there e.g. the background color stays black

Answer (score 5):

the [setColorized](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html#setColorized(boolean)) documentation says:

> Set whether this notification should be colorized. When set, the color set with **setColor(int)** will be used as the **background color** of this notification.
>
> This should only be used for high priority ongoing tasks like navigation, an ongoing call, or other similarly high-priority events for the user.
>
> For most styles, the **coloring will only be applied if the notification is for a foreground service notification.**
>
> However, for **MediaStyle and DecoratedMediaCustomViewStyle notifications that have a media session attached there is no such requirement.**
>
> Calling this method on any version prior to O will not have an effect on the notification and it won't be colorized.

Kotlin code:

```
import android.support.v4.media.session.MediaSessionCompat
import android.support.v4.media.session.PlaybackStateCompat
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat
import androidx.media.app.NotificationCompat.DecoratedMediaCustomViewStyle

// create a MediaSession so that we can create a DecoratedMediaCustomViewStyle
val mediaSession = MediaSessionCompat(applicationContext,"tag")
mediaSession.setFlags(0)
mediaSession.setPlaybackState(PlaybackStateCompat.Builder()
        .setState(PlaybackStateCompat.STATE_NONE,0,0f)
        .build())

// create & display the colorized notification
notificationManager.notify(
        0,
        NotificationCompat
                .Builder(this,notificationChannel)
                .setStyle(DecoratedMediaCustomViewStyle()
                        .setMediaSession(mediaSession.sessionToken))
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_app_foreground)
                .setColor(getColor(android.R.color.black))
                .setColorized(true)
                .setContentText("Hello, World!")
                .build())

....

// cleanup upon dismissing the notification
mediaSession.release()
```