# how to show notification in lower APIs within dark color of notification panel in android?

Tags: android, notifications

I use this code for showing notification in my app. as I run it API 16,because of notification dark color, it seems that nothing shows in notification panel. what should I do?

```
   private void setupNotification(String s) {
 Intent notificationIntent_Restore = new Intent(this,Adult1Activity.class);
 notificationIntent_Restore.putExtra(EXTRA_NOTE,NOTE_RESTORE);
 PendingIntent restoreIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,
 0, notificationIntent_Restore, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

 final Intent notificationIntent_Close = new Intent(this, Adult1Activity.class);
 notificationIntent_Close.putExtra(EXTRA_NOTE, NOTE_CLOSE);
 PendingIntent closeIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,
         1, notificationIntent_Close, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


     if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 16) {
         Notification n  = new Notification.Builder(this)
                 .setContentTitle("Stand Up!")
                 .setContentText(s)
                 .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                 .setContentIntent(restoreIntent)
                 .setAutoCancel(true)
                 .setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white_color))
                 .getNotification();
         NotificationManager notificationManager =
                 (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
         notificationManager.notify(0, n);
     } else {
         notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                 .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                 .setContentTitle("Stand Up!")
                 .setContentText(s)
                 .setAutoCancel(true)
                 .setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black_color))
                 .addAction(new NotificationCompat.Action(R.drawable.ic_note_restore, "Restore", restoreIntent))
                 .addAction(new NotificationCompat.Action(R.drawable.ic_note_close, "Close", closeIntent))
                 .setContentIntent(restoreIntent)
                 .build();
         NotificationManager notificationManager =
                 (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        // notificationManager.notify();
     }

 startForeground(notification_id, notification);

 }
```

this is the app logs:

```
    D/dalvikvm: Late-enabling CheckJNI
I/ActivityThread: Pub standup.maxsoft.com.standup.google_measurement_service: com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementContentProvider
 I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.app.Notification$Builder.setLocalOnly, referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.zza
01-09 16:42:07.805 9191-9191/standup.maxsoft.com.standup W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 256: Landroid/app/Notification$Builder;.setLocalOnly (Z)Landroid/app/Notification$Builder;
01-09 16:42:07.805 9191-9191/standup.maxsoft.com.standup D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x00c8
01-09 16:42:07.805 9191-9191/standup.maxsoft.com.standup I/dalvikvm: DexOpt: access denied from Lcom/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesUtil; to field Landroid/app/Notification;.extras
01-09 16:42:07.805 9191-9191/standup.maxsoft.com.standup W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve instance field 18
01-09 16:42:07.805 9191-9191/standup.maxsoft.com.standup D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x54 at 0x00e7
01-09 16:42:07.825 9191-9191/standup.maxsoft.com.standup E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.UserManager', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.zzap
01-09 16:42:07.825 9191-9191/standup.maxsoft.com.standup W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 287 (Landroid/os/UserManager;) in Lcom/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesUtil;
01-09 16:42:07.825 9191-9191/standup.maxsoft.com.standup D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x1f at 0x000c
01-09 16:42:07.825 9191-9191/standup.maxsoft.com.standup E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.AppOpsManager', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.zzb
01-09 16:42:07.825 9191-9191/standup.maxsoft.com.standup W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 27 (Landroid/app/AppOpsManager;) in Lcom/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesUtil;
01-09 16:42:07.825 9191-9191/standup.maxsoft.com.standup D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x1f at 0x000e
01-09 16:42:07.825 9191-9191/standup.maxsoft.com.standup I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.pm.PackageManager.getPackageInstaller, referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.zzh
01-09 16:42:07.825 9191-9191/standup.maxsoft.com.standup W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 563: Landroid/content/pm/PackageManager;.getPackageInstaller ()Landroid/content/pm/PackageInstaller;
01-09 16:42:07.825 9191-9191/standup.maxsoft.com.standup D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x000b
01-09 16:42:07.865 9191-9194/standup.maxsoft.com.standup D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 215K, 11% free 7253K/8071K, paused 12ms+2ms, total 31ms
01-09 16:42:07.865 9191-9191/standup.maxsoft.com.standup D/dalvikvm: WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 11ms
01-09 16:42:07.880 9191-9225/standup.maxsoft.com.standup I/GMPM: App measurement is starting up
01-09 16:42:07.885 9191-9225/standup.maxsoft.com.standup E/GMPM: getGoogleAppId failed with status: 10
01-09 16:42:07.890 9191-9225/standup.maxsoft.com.standup E/GMPM: Uploading is not possible. App measurement disabled
01-09 16:42:07.895 9191-9191/standup.maxsoft.com.standup I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.Window.setStatusBarColor, referenced from method standup.maxsoft.com.standup.help.HelpActivity.changeStatusBarColor
01-09 16:42:07.895 9191-9191/standup.maxsoft.com.standup W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 19558: Landroid/view/Window;.setStatusBarColor (I)V
01-09 16:42:07.895 9191-9191/standup.maxsoft.com.standup D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0010
01-09 16:42:08.210 9191-9191/standup.maxsoft.com.standup W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)
01-09 16:42:08.210 9191-9191/standup.maxsoft.com.standup I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onSearchRequested, referenced from method android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onSearchRequested
01-09 16:42:08.210 9191-9191/standup.maxsoft.com.standup W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 19539: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onSearchRequested (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)Z
01-09 16:42:08.210 9191-9191/standup.maxsoft.com.standup D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
01-09 16:42:08.210 9191-9191/standup.maxsoft.com.standup I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onWindowStartingActionMode, referenced from method android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onWindowStartingActionMode
01-09 16:42:08.210 9191-9191/standup.maxsoft.com.standup W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 19543: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onWindowStartingActionMode (Landroid/view/ActionMode$Callback;I)Landroid/view/ActionMode;
01-09 16:42:08.210 9191-9191/standup.maxsoft.com.standup D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
01-09 16:42:08.235 9191-9194/standup.maxsoft.com.standup D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 326K, 12% free 7372K/8327K, paused 2ms+2ms, total 30ms
01-09 16:42:08.385 9191-9191/standup.maxsoft.com.standup I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.ViewGroup.onRtlPropertiesChanged, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.onRtlPropertiesChanged
01-09 16:42:08.385 9191-9191/standup.maxsoft.com.standup W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 19429: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.onRtlPropertiesChanged (I)V
01-09 16:42:08.385 9191-9191/standup.maxsoft.com.standup D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0007
01-09 16:42:08.405 9191-9191/standup.maxsoft.com.standup I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getChangingConfigurations, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getChangingConfigurations
01-09 16:42:08.405 9191-9191/standup.maxsoft.com.standup W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 641: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations ()I
01-09 16:42:08.405 9191-9191/standup.maxsoft.com.standup D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
01-09 16:42:08.405 9191-9191/standup.maxsoft.com.standup I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getType, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getType
01-09 16:42:08.405 9191-9191/standup.maxsoft.com.standup W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 663: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType (I)I
01-09 16:42:08.405 9191-9191/standup.maxsoft.com.standup D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
01-09 16:42:08.465 9191-9191/standup.maxsoft.com.standup D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 74K, 11% free 7420K/8327K, paused 40ms, total 40ms
01-09 16:42:08.515 9191-9191/standup.maxsoft.com.standup D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 6K, 12% free 7620K/8583K, paused 28ms, total 28ms
01-09 16:42:08.515 9191-9191/standup.maxsoft.com.standup I/dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap (frag case) to 8.251MB for 232944-byte allocation
01-09 16:42:08.570 9191-9191/standup.maxsoft.com.standup D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 12% free 7847K/8839K, paused 45ms, total 45ms
01-09 16:42:08.660 9191-9191/standup.maxsoft.com.standup D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_mali.so
01-09 16:42:08.665 9191-9191/standup.maxsoft.com.standup D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_mali.so
01-09 16:42:08.670 9191-9191/standup.maxsoft.com.standup D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_mali.so
01-09 16:42:08.720 9191-9191/standup.maxsoft.com.standup D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
01-09 16:42:08.730 9191-9191/standup.maxsoft.com.standup I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutCompat.drawableHotspotChanged, referenced from method android.support.design.internal.ForegroundLinearLayout.drawableHotspotChanged
01-09 16:42:08.730 9191-9191/standup.maxsoft.com.standup W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 16196: Landroid/support/v7/widget/LinearLayoutCompat;.drawableHotspotChanged (FF)V
01-09 16:42:08.730 9191-9191/standup.maxsoft.com.standup D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0000
01-09 16:42:08.750 9191-9191/standup.maxsoft.com.standup W/ResourceType: Skipping entry 0x108038e in package table 0 because it is not complex!
01-09 16:42:08.750 9191-9191/standup.maxsoft.com.standup W/ResourceType: Skipping entry 0x108038e in package table 0 because it is not complex!
01-09 16:42:08.750 9191-9191/standup.maxsoft.com.standup W/ResourceType: Skipping entry 0x108038e in package table 0 because it is not complex!
01-09 16:42:08.750 9191-9191/standup.maxsoft.com.standup W/ResourceType: Skipping entry 0x108038e in package table 0 because it is not complex!
01-09 16:42:08.750 9191-9191/standup.maxsoft.com.standup W/ResourceType: Skipping entry 0x108038e in package table 0 because it is not complex!
01-09 16:42:08.750 9191-9191/standup.maxsoft.com.standup W/ResourceType: Skipping entry 0x108038e in package table 0 because it is not complex!
01-09 16:42:08.750 9191-9191/standup.maxsoft.com.standup W/ResourceType: Skipping entry 0x108038e in package table 0 because it is not complex!
01-09 16:42:08.750 9191-9191/standup.maxsoft.com.standup W/ResourceType: Skipping entry 0x108038e in package table 0 because it is not complex!
01-09 16:42:08.760 9191-9191/standup.maxsoft.com.standup W/ResourceType: Skipping entry 0x108038e in package table 0 because it is not complex!
01-09 16:42:08.760 9191-9191/standup.maxsoft.com.standup W/ResourceType: Skipping entry 0x108038e in package table 0 because it is not complex!
01-09 16:42:08.760 9191-9191/standup.maxsoft.com.standup W/ResourceType: Skipping entry 0x108038e in package table 0 because it is not complex!
01-09 16:42:08.760 9191-9191/standup.maxsoft.com.standup W/ResourceType: Skipping entry 0x108038e in package table 0 because it is not complex!
01-09 16:42:08.760 9191-9191/standup.maxsoft.com.standup W/ResourceType: Skipping entry 0x108038e in package table 0 because it is not complex!
01-09 16:42:08.760 9191-9191/standup.maxsoft.com.standup W/ResourceType: Skipping entry 0x108038e in package table 0 because it is not complex!
01-09 16:42:08.760 9191-9191/standup.maxsoft.com.standup W/ResourceType: Skipping entry 0x108038e in package table 0 because it is not complex!
01-09 16:42:08.760 9191-9191/standup.maxsoft.com.standup W/ResourceType: Skipping entry 0x108038e in package table 0 because it is not complex!
01-09 16:42:08.780 9191-9191/standup.maxsoft.com.standup W/ResourceType: Skipping entry 0x108038e in package table 0 because it is not complex!
01-09 16:42:08.780 9191-9191/standup.maxsoft.com.standup W/ResourceType: Skipping entry 0x108038e in package table 0 because it is not complex!
01-09 16:42:08.780 9191-9191/standup.maxsoft.com.standup W/ResourceType: Skipping entry 0x108038e in package table 0 because it is not complex!
01-09 16:42:08.780 9191-9191/standup.maxsoft.com.standup W/ResourceType: Skipping entry 0x108038e in package table 0 because it is not complex!
01-09 16:42:08.780 9191-9191/standup.maxsoft.com.standup W/ResourceType: Skipping entry 0x108038e in package table 0 because it is not complex!
01-09 16:42:08.780 9191-9191/standup.maxsoft.com.standup W/ResourceType: Skipping entry 0x108038e in package table 0 because it is not complex!
01-09 16:42:08.780 9191-9191/standup.maxsoft.com.standup W/ResourceType: Skipping entry 0x108038e in package table 0 because it is not complex!
01-09 16:42:08.780 9191-9191/standup.maxsoft.com.standup W/ResourceType: Skipping entry 0x108038e in package table 0 because it is not complex!
01-09 16:42:08.780 9191-9191/standup.maxsoft.com.standup W/ResourceType: Skipping entry 0x108038e in package table 0 because it is not complex!
01-09 16:42:08.780 9191-9191/standup.maxsoft.com.standup W/ResourceType: Skipping entry 0x108038e in package table 0 because it is not complex!
01-09 16:42:08.785 9191-9191/standup.maxsoft.com.standup W/ResourceType: Skipping entry 0x108038e in package table 0 because it is not complex!
01-09 16:42:08.785 9191-9191/standup.maxsoft.com.standup W/ResourceType: Skipping entry 0x108038e in package table 0 because it is not complex!
01-09 16:42:08.785 9191-9191/standup.maxsoft.com.standup W/ResourceType: Skipping entry 0x108038e in package table 0 because it is not complex!
01-09 16:42:08.785 9191-9191/standup.maxsoft.com.standup W/ResourceType: Skipping entry 0x108038e in package table 0 because it is not complex!
01-09 16:42:08.785 9191-9191/standup.maxsoft.com.standup W/ResourceType: Skipping entry 0x108038e in package table 0 because it is not complex!
01-09 16:42:08.785 9191-9191/standup.maxsoft.com.standup W/ResourceType: Skipping entry 0x108038e in package table 0 because it is not complex!
01-09 16:42:08.800 9191-9194/standup.maxsoft.com.standup D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 98K, 9% free 8181K/8903K, paused 18ms+14ms, total 65ms
01-09 16:42:08.810 9191-9191/standup.maxsoft.com.standup W/ResourceType: Skipping entry 0x108038e in package table 0 because it is not complex!
01-09 16:42:08.810 9191-9191/standup.maxsoft.com.standup W/ResourceType: Skipping entry 0x108038e in package table 0 because it is not complex!
01-09 16:42:08.810 9191-9191/standup.maxsoft.com.standup W/ResourceType: Skipping entry 0x108038e in package table 0 because it is not complex!
01-09 16:42:08.810 9191-9191/standup.maxsoft.com.standup W/ResourceType: Skipping entry 0x108038e in package table 0 because it is not complex!
01-09 16:42:08.810 9191-9191/standup.maxsoft.com.standup W/ResourceType: Skipping entry 0x108038e in package table 0 because it is not complex!
01-09 16:42:08.810 9191-9191/standup.maxsoft.com.standup W/ResourceType: Skipping entry 0x108038e in package table 0 because it is not complex!
01-09 16:42:08.810 9191-9191/standup.maxsoft.com.standup W/ResourceType: Skipping entry 0x108038e in package table 0 because it is not complex!
01-09 16:42:08.810 9191-9191/standup.maxsoft.com.standup W/ResourceType: Skipping entry 0x108038e in package table 0 because it is not complex!
01-09 16:42:12.975 9191-9191/standup.maxsoft.com.standup I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.app.Notification$Builder.setColor, referenced from method standup.maxsoft.com.standup.home.TimerService.setupNotification
01-09 16:42:12.975 9191-9191/standup.maxsoft.com.standup W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 242: Landroid/app/Notification$Builder;.setColor (I)Landroid/app/Notification$Builder;
01-09 16:42:12.975 9191-9191/standup.maxsoft.com.standup D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0056
01-09 16:42:13.265 9191-9191/standup.maxsoft.com.standup E/SpannableStringBuilder: SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
01-09 16:42:13.265 9191-9191/standup.maxsoft.com.standup E/SpannableStringBuilder: SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
01-09 16:42:33.510 9191-9194/standup.maxsoft.com.standup D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 318K, 11% free 8307K/9287K, paused 23ms+4ms, total 60ms
01-09 16:43:04.520 9191-9194/standup.maxsoft.com.standup D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 474K, 13% free 8276K/9415K, paused 2ms+3ms, total 30ms
01-09 16:43:31.615 9191-9194/standup.maxsoft.com.standup D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 384K, 13% free 8277K/9415K, paused 21ms+3ms, total 67ms
01-09 16:43:58.650 9191-9194/standup.maxsoft.com.standup D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 385K, 13% free 8277K/9415K, paused 8ms+3ms, total 54ms
01-09 16:44:25.655 9191-9194/standup.maxsoft.com.standup D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 385K, 13% free 8277K/9415K, paused 2ms+2ms, total 22ms
 91919191/standup.maxsoft.com.stW/IInputConnectionWrapper: getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
 W/IInputConnectionWrapper: setComposingText on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection
 D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 387K, 13% free 8278K/9415K, paused 37ms+1ms, total 76ms
E/SpannableStringBuilder: SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
 E/SpannableStringBuilder: SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper: setComposingText on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection
```

this is the notification picture(this is Samsung-GTN8000 with android version 4.1.2) :

[image]

instead of:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think it will be better to follow official [status bar icon guidelines](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_status_bar.html) and change icon color to white.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your issue can be resolved by setting a background color.
So that this can be overcomed.

Hope this answer works:
[Changing Notification RemoteViews Background Color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38022141/changing-notification-remoteviews-background-color)

**EDIT :**

Providing you the working code to make notifications text visible in any version of android devices.

The back background is specific to OS in Kitkat and below OS. Trying using this and provide your feedback.

```
private void buildNotifications() {

    Intent notificationIntent_Restore = new Intent(this,Adult1Activity.class);
 notificationIntent_Restore.putExtra(EXTRA_NOTE,NOTE_RESTORE);
 PendingIntent restoreIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,
 0, notificationIntent_Restore, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setLargeIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentIntent(clickIntent)
                .setContentTitle("Stand Up!")
                .setContentText(s)
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                .addAction(R.drawable.ic_skip_previous_white_36dp,
                        "",
                        retrievePlaybackAction(PREVIOUS_ACTION))
                .addAction(playButtonResId, "",
                        retrievePlaybackAction(TOGGLEPAUSE_ACTION))
                .addAction(R.drawable.ic_skip_next_white_36dp,
                        "",
                        retrievePlaybackAction(NEXT_ACTION));

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
            builder.setShowWhen(false);
        }
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            builder.setVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC);
            NotificationCompat.MediaStyle style = new NotificationCompat.MediaStyle()
                    .setShowActionsInCompactView(0, 1, 2, 3);
            builder.setStyle(style);
        }
        builder.setColor(Color.parseColor("#403f4d"));
        Notification n = builder.build();

startForeground(notificationId, n);
}
```

Comment: Migutanar could you please provide a screenshot of your exact issue and the way that you are expecting your output to be so that we can have clear idea.

Comment: ChaitanyaAtkuri . I upload the photo and all logs. I see that notification shows very speedly,but most of the time it is empty and dark.

Comment: Also provide the screenshot for your expectation and also mention the device name in which you are experiencing this.

Comment: there is a problem in `NotificationCompat.MediaStyle style = new NotificationCompat.MediaStyle()
                     .setMediaSession(mSession.getSessionToken())
                     .setShowActionsInCompactView(0, 1, 2, 3);
             builder.setStyle(style);` what are the `MediaStyle ` and `mSession`?

Comment: @Migitanar make sure your use the right import.

import android.support.v7.app.NotificationCompat;

Comment: how about `mSession`? it is not initialize.

Comment: MediaSession() is for uniquely identifying the session. But for your case, there is no need for that. I also have updated the code accordingly. Try it and lemme know.

Comment: I do it, but nothing show again. `E/SpannableStringBuilder: SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
E/SpannableStringBuilder: SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
E/SpannableStringBuilder: SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
E/SpannableStringBuilder: SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
E/SpannableStringBuilder: SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
E/SpannableStringBuilder: SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length`